# Issue configuring SimpleSamlPhp with ADFS

Tags: php, single-sign-on, adfs, simplesamlphp

I'm having some difficulties to configure SimpleSamlPhp with ADFS.

Here is the procedure that I have followed:

SimpleSAML is installed and configured on my web server 
Apache (example.com) and ADFS2 is installed on your federation 
server (myadfs).

- Open a browser and go to URL `https://myadfs/Federationmetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml`
- Save as `FederationMetadata.xml`.
- Open a browser and go to `https://example.com/simplesaml`
- Select Federation tab
- Click on *Convert XML Metadata to simpleSAML.php*
- Paste the content of the previous file (FederationMetadata.xml)
- Click on Analyse
- On saml20-idp-remote section, select all text and copy it
- Edit the file `<document_root>/simplesamlphp/metadata/saml20-idp-remote.php` (save a copy like `saml20-idp-remote.bak`)
- Delete all text between `<?php … ?>` (keep the `<?php` and `?>`)
- Paste the previous selected text between `<?php` and `?>`
- Under `entityid` line, add following line: `'sign.logout' => TRUE,`
- Save `saml20-idp-remote.php`
- Edit the file `<document_root>/simplesamlphp/config/ 
  authsources.php`. In the $config array add an entry like

  ```
  'myauth' => array( 
      'saml:SP', 
      'idp' => 'http://www.myadfs.com/adfs/services/trust', 
      'privatekey' => '001-mysite.key', 
      'certificate' => '001-mysite.crt', 
  ),
  ```

Then I sent my Metadata to my network administrator for him to authorize my connection.

Unfortunately when I try to connect I directly get the ADFS error without being able to input my credentials.

My Network Administrator told me that the error was the following:

> The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Apparently he cannot read the certificate on a windows server but we have successfully installed Wordpress SSO on Microsoft Azure using a plugin that use this exact same PHP Plugin and it has been working fine.

Does someone have any idea how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thanks for the steps, I found them really helpful. Did you get any further with your error?